# Problem accessing specific elements of all objects in an array using Handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I'm relatively new to Handlebars so this might some something simple that I'm missing, but I can't seem to output specific elements of every object in an array. I've searched through multiple posts and read the handlebars documentation, but so far haven't found a solution. Basically I'm trying to output the availability for a series of time slots and their statuses that are assigned to one item. Here's my code...

**Data**

```
Pitch: {
"name": "test",
"price": 11,
"city": "testCity",
"availability": [
    {
        "status": "reserved",
        "dt": "2018-11-16T20:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "status": "available",
        "dt": "2018-11-16T19:00:00Z"
    }
]
}
```

**index.js**

```
router.get('/availability/:id', function(req, res, next) {
Pitch.findById(req.params.id, function (err, docs){
    var indPitch = [];
    indPitch.push(docs);

    res.render('pitch/availability', { title: 'Availability', indPitch: indPitch });

});
```

**availability.hbs**

```
{{#each indPitch}}
        <h3><a href="/availability/{{ id }}">{{ name }}</a></h3>
        <p class = "description">{{ city }}</p>
        {{#each availability}}
          {{status}}
          {{dt}}
        {{/each}}
        <p class = "description">Price per hour : €{{ price }}</p>
        <a href="/reserve/{{id}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" role="button">Select</a>
{{/each}}
```

With the handlebars code above, only the city and price are output to the screen. If I change {{#each availability}} to {{#each this}} and then access the object as {{availability.[0].status}} or {{availability.[1].dt}}, etc. I can then output that item to the screen.

But, what I need to do is loop through 'Availability' for the item and display all date/times and their status. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? If you need more information, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a few hours of trying every combination of #each this and #each availability, eventually one worked. Posting the answer here incase anyone else has the same problem...

I had to nest {{#each availabilty}} inside an {{#each this}} as follows...

```
{{#each indPitch}}
<h3><a href="/availability/{{ id }}">{{this.name }}</a></h3>
<p class = "description">{{ this.city }}</p>
{{#each this}}    
    {{#each availability}}
        {{status}}
        {{dt}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
<p class = "description">Price per hour : €{{ this.price }}</p>
<a href="/reserve/{{this.id}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" role="button">Select</a>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this before each element this should work

```
 {{#each indPitch}}
    <h3><a href="/availability/{{ id }}">{{this.name }}</a></h3>
    <p class = "description">{{ this.city }}</p>
    {{#each availability}}
      {{this.status}}
      {{this.dt}}
    {{/each}}
    <p class = "description">Price per hour : €{{ this.price }}</p>
    <a href="/reserve/{{this.id}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" role="button">Select</a>
```

{{/each}}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that still only outputs the name, city, and price to the screen - and not the status or dt. I'm a bit stumped as to why it won't output those.